# Waiting for button press within for loop?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 audio files, this.audio1 and this.audio2. For each trial, the user is supposed to choose whether the two files are the same or different. So, I want to play the two audio files one after each other, wait for the use to click the same or different button, and then go to the next trial. This is my code so far for playing the audio files:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.numTrials; i++){ 
   var audio1; // these are actually initialized, obviously, in my code
   var audio2; 
   var noRepeat = true;
   audio1.addEventListener('ended', function () {
       if (noRepeat) {
            audio2.play();
            noRepeat = false;
       }
   });
   audio2.addEventListener('ended', function () {
      game.audioComplete = true;
   });
   audio1.play();

   // here, I want to add code so it waits until a button is pressed before moving on

}
```

I tried an eventListener where my comment is, which didn't work (it just kept looping through anyway). Does anyone have any suggestions for what I could use to "pause" the loop and wait for the button press, and then have it move on?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just have 1 button play audio files and increment a counter that you compare with `numTrials` when its pressed instead of having it "unpause" the current loop? That would get rid of the loop altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, this is the same as what [@fixatd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5876384/fixatd) commented.

```
var globalPlayCount = 0;
...
function play() {
  if(globalPlayCount < this.numTrials) {
    globalPlayCount++:
    audio1.play();
  }
}
...
```

Fire `play()` on your button click. Just make sure you have both your event listeners intact.

Comment: Ah. That sounds like a much better idea. Do you know how I might wait/ "pause" the audio for like 2-3 seconds? Right now, it's starting basically immediately after I press the button, and I want it to start a few seconds after. Thanks!

Comment: @sy89, Use setTimeout() for that.

Comment: @sy89. Use them inside your listeners.